# What is the basis of $ \tau$ generated by S

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then $S=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3,4\},\{2,3\}\}$ is a subbasis for a topology  $\tau$. I would like to find the base of  $\tau$ generated by $S$.

Comment: What is the definition of subbasis that you're using? There are two definitions commonly used that are not always equivalent

Comment: @ Bey A subbasis for X, is a collection S of open subsets of X s.t. the collection of all intersections of finite subcollections of S is a base for X.

Comment: I think this definition is not correct: with this definition, a subbasis might not generate the basis for a topology. For example, the collection $S$ you posted above. Based on your definition, the collection $S$ will not generate a basis. My suspicion is that you're accidentally leaving something out of the definition

Comment: @ Bey Let me try again. I'm writing it directly from the text.Let X be a topological space. A subbase for the topology on X,also called a subbase for X,is a collection S of open subsets of X s.t. the collection of all intersections of finite subcollections of S is a base for X.

Comment: @ Bey Maybe the definition includes intersection with itself?

Comment: Ah, yes, taking into account self-intersections will do it. The definition isn't wrong, I just wasn't including those particular intersections (of sets with themselves). Try writing out the basis now

Comment: @Klara: Now that you know that you have to include the members of $S$, you can write up your answer, post it, and (after several hours) accept it; this is encouraged. That will take the question off the Unanswered list and increase your reputation in the process.

Comment: @ Brian, What do you think of my answer. I had a hard time creating the element {1,2,3}  and I needed that inside the base. I imagined {1,2,3}=Intersection of {{1,2},{2,3,4}} with {{1,2},{2,3}}. Is this right.

Comment: The set {1,2,3} should not be in the basis.

Comment: @Bey Yes I looked at a definition of checking up a base and I realised I did not need that!

Answer (score 1):

The set {{1,2},{2,3,4},{2},{2,3}} is the basis that is created by the subbasis S.